# How to say "often" in an imperative sentence? (eg. "come back often baby")

Tags: word-choice

Can I just say 常常/经常....吧? Or should I use 多？

> 常常回来吧 / 经常回来吧 / 多回来宝贝

Or is there a better way of phrasing this? I tried searching the internet but couldn't find anything that resolves my query. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

It's right,but we often say"常常回来哦/经常回来哦/多回来哦宝贝"in oral Chinese.

Answer (score 3):

"Come back often baby!" Depends I suppose on how familiar you are with 'baby,' but if you need to tell her this, probably not sooo familiar.

I think I prefer:

Come back any time you like babe/sweetheart/darlin'!

你想什么时候再过来都可以，宝贝/甜心/亲爱的。

A salesperson, a prostitute, a waiter in a restaurant might say to a customer:

以后常来哦！